# Slope of a function very much less than the function

Tags: calculus, functions, differential

I was working on a Cosmology problem and got stuck at this approximation used in a paper. Fundamentally the approximation is, $\frac{df(x)}{dx} \ll f(x)$. Now I can't understand how to imagine this situation graphically, also what it means physically.

I tried to look up this question on the web and on this website but could not find anything close-by. Sorry if the question is badly phrased, I could not think of a better way to write it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, $f(x) = c$; $f'(x) = 0$; $0 \ll c$?

Comment: $f(x)=10^{23}+x$ too. Could you give us an idea of the equation ?

Comment: First, how do you guys write in Latex here? Otherwise the equation wont make much sense to anyone.

Comment: A $\LaTeX$ tutorial is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Basically you put it in dollar signs.

Comment: Cool. So the function $f(x)$ is of the form $\frac{g(x)-h(x)}{g(x)}$. Initially the functions are equal but as x increases the functions are no longer equal and $f(x) \ne 0$.

Comment: That becomes $1-\frac {h(x)}{g(x)}$ and doesn't explain why $f' \ll f$. It might be true, it might not.

Comment: Ok, so I though of a way to visualize it. I was trying to look at this as a graph of $f(x)$ and its slope $f'(x)$. But then I realized I could think of it as two graphs $f(x) and f'(x)$ against $x$. Then I can see what it means graphically. And the only physical explanation I can make out of it is that $f(x)$ starts with some value but the rate of its change with respect to $x, i.e. f'(x),$ is smaller than $f(x)$ it self.

Comment: Any  commetns or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It can be true or false, depending on $f(x)$.  Note that $x$ must be unitless for the comparison to make sense.  An extreme case would be $f(x)$ is a large constant-that would make the derivative zero.  Large and almost constant would also satisfy the relation.

Note that rescaling $x$ can change this.  If we define $y=100x$ we have $\frac {df(y)}{dy}=100\frac {df(100x)}{dx}$ and the $\ll$ might not be satisfied.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying but f(x) is not a constant. It is a function of x.

Comment: That was an example of one function that satisfies the approximation.  $x+c$ is another if $c$ is large.

Comment: So the function $f(x)$ is of the form $\frac{g(x)-h(x)}{g(x)}$. Initially the functions are equal but as x increases the functions are no longer equal and $f(x) \ne 0$.